# linux - make .a corresponding to .so

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, symbols

I have some legacy `'so'` file, with the corresponding `header`, how to make `'a'` file out of it
to link with the project ?

(or could I link to `'so'` - adding `-L/path_to_so/` and `-lsomething` (assuming so is in /path_to_so and is named libsomething.so does not seem to work - ld complains about missing exports - but they are present in lib (lib is 32bit, -m32 is used, project is 32bit) ?)

I'm not a linux guru, on windows when i have `dll` and `header` I'm able to generate lib, that I'm linking with project to use dll - I assume that same is on linux right ?

Comment: You probably don't need to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413563/how-to-generate-import-libray-libsample-a-from-dynamic-library-libsample-so

Comment: Show your commands and the error message.

Answer (score 3):

> I have some legacy 'so' file, with the corresponding header, how to make 'a' file out of it to link with the project ?

There is no way to make `.a`. from `.so`. On Linux `.so` get linked directly, no import library is required.